# How to merge an array of Observables into a single Observable of the same return type

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming, ngrx

What I am trying to achieve is push a few http request observables in an array and then combine all the responses and return with a single observable.

Since all the http requests resolve with the same type 'User', I just want to wait for all of them to resolve and then I can return a single observable with all Users from getUsers() function.

I'm stuck at the `return merge(observableRequests)` part as I can't get the return type right and I'm not too versed in Rxjs functions.

Here are my three related functions.

```
    getMyUser(): Observable<User> {
        return this.service.get(`${this._userPath}me`).pipe(
            map((serviceUser: any) => {
                return parseUser(serviceUser);
            }));
    }

    getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
        return this.getMyUser()
            .pipe(switchMap((user: User) => {
                const activeProvidersIds = this._getActiveProvidersIds(user.providers);
                const observableRequests = activeProvidersIds.map((id: number) => this.getUserRequest(id));
                return merge(observableRequests);
            }));
    }

    getUserRequest(facDbk: number): Observable<User[]> {
        return this.service.get(`${this._providerPath}${facDbk}/users`).pipe(
            map((serviceUsers: any) => {
                return parseUsers(serviceUsers);
            })
        );
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ForkJoin will work in your use case, you can follow this code

```js
import { Observable, of, forkJoin } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface user {
  id : string;
  name: string;
}

// mimicking api requests
const httpRequest = (num): Observable<user> =>{
  return Observable.create((observer)=>{
    const [id,name] = [`id-${num}`,`name-${num}`];
    setTimeout(()=>{
     observer.next({id,name});
     observer.complete();
    },num*1000);
  });
}

//push array of request observables and return single observable
// you can push any number of request here 
const makeRequestInParallel = ():Observable<user> =>{
  const reqs:Observable<user>[] = [httpRequest(1),httpRequest(2),httpRequest(3)];
  return forkJoin(...reqs);
}


makeRequestInParallel().subscribe((result)=>{
  console.log(result);
});
```

click [stablitz-link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-97vrsv)

Comment: I literally spent hours searching for this solution. I wish they named forkJoin something a bit more obvious. Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for `forkJoin`:

`When all observables complete, emit the last emitted value from each.`

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Here is an example that may helps you:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-seuqh5

Comment: forkJoin() would make the function return an Observable<Observable<User[]>>. Not quite what I need.

Comment: You can combine with `combineLatest` too, I will give an example.

Comment: I added a stackblitz link in the answer, please, tell me if it solves your problem.

Comment: The problem was that I would not know how many observables there'd be to resolve. It depends on how many active facilities the user has (from the code). However, forkJoin() was indeed the way to go. All I had to do was use the spread operator before passing array of observables parameter. If you edit your original answer, I'd be happy to accept your answer.